# Funding for writing a computer science dissertation

Tags: phd, thesis, funding, computer-science

When I look around, most of the funding opportunities in computer science require a PhD to hold.

Now, I have finished the courses part of my doctoral school and have a reviewed research proposal. Are there funding bodies that allow to apply for a grant to work solely on my journal papers and dissertation for a year?

I think I could make an advance, not having to teach classes what I otherwise do for a living.

I work in the EU.

Is this highly unusual, or there are organisations who would support this?

Comment: What you want is a stipend.

Answer (score 2):

There exists funding for PhD, yes.

As always with such questions, it is better to ask locally instead of asking random people on the Internet.
Ask your advisor (if you already have one in mind), ask the student office at the university, ask other PhD students, ask the student counselor (if you have one; take the one for administrative and study questions, not the mental health one^^).

Comment: I would like to know about international, especially EU funding.

Comment: @Gergely What difference does it make where the money comes from? Are Euros more valuable if they come over the border? And forget about EU, they think in billions, not 50k €.

Comment: @Karl At the graduate school there is a predoctoral scholarship -- only for students who have done their first years already on scholarship. And 10k euro would be enough, on that I could even travel which would be quite beneficial.

Comment: In my country, there are no scolarships for me, that's why I ask here